# WCF Throttling - Rational behind the default values

Tags: wcf, throttling

The default values are

- Concurrent Calls: 16 * processor count
- Concurrent Sessions: 100 * processor count
- Concurrent Instances: Concurrent Calls + Concurrent Sessions

This is fine. But I am trying to understand the rationale behind the default value for Concurrent Instances. **Why its sum of other two? Can somebody demystify? please**

Note: *Yes, we can override the values as we like.*

Answer (score 0):

From Wenlong Dong's old Blog: [WCF 4: Higher Default Throttling Settings for WCF Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2009/07/26/wcf-4-higher-default-throttling-settings-for-wcf-services.aspx)

> The main purpose for the throttling settings can be classified into
>   the following two aspects:
>
> 1. Controlled resource usage: With the throttling of concurrent execution, the usage of resources such as memory or threads can be
>      limited to a reasonable level so that the system works well without
>      hitting reliability issues.
> 2. Balanced performance load: Systems always work in a balanced way when the load is controlled. If there are too much concurrent
>      execution happening, a lot of contention and bookkeeping would happen
>      and thus it would hurt the performance of the system.

There's more detail in the blog...

Answer (score 0):

A service can have its SessionMode set to [Allowed, NotAllowed, or Required](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.sessionmode(v=vs.110).aspx), so the instancing behaviour of the service can depend on the incoming connections. Look at the "Allowed" column of the table at the bottom of this documentation for ["Sessions, Instancing, and Concurrency"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193(v=vs.110).aspx).

It allows an instance per session and an instance per call, depending on the connecting channels.

So the instance limit should be the sum of the session and call limits.